# Itext: Iterate through row and get linked values

Tags: c#, sql, itext

I have my DB as followed:

Person

- PersonID
- Name

Animal

- AnimalID
- PersonID
- PetName

What I'm trying to achieve is to export my persons and their linked animals to PDF.

Example:

John Doe:

- animal1
- animal2

Bob:

- Animal2
- Animal3

(animals can be linked to the same person).

I have an issue with the iTextSharp export to PDF module since I failed to find cases where a join principe is handled.

I now am able to export my persons without a problem by retrieving them from SQL and putting them in a `DataTable` that I implement as followed:

```
DataTable dt = getPersons();
iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document();

PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("C:\\sample.pdf", FileMode.Create));
document.Open();

table.SetWidths(widths);

table.WidthPercentage = 100;
int iCol = 0;
string colname = "";
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Persons:"));

cell.Colspan = dt.Columns.Count;

foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
{

    table.AddCell(new Phrase(c.ColumnName, font5));
}

foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
{
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[0].ToString(), font5));
        table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[1].ToString(), font5));
        table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[2].ToString(), font5));
        table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[3].ToString(), font5));
    }
}


document.Add(table);
document.Close();
```

This retrieves the persons from my database (as in a ´SELECT * FROM person´).

However, how would I implement the link with the animals (for each person) in my pdf (using only SQL statements as i do this at runtime for preview reasons only)?

Would I need need to work with 2 DataTables or could I do this another way?

Comment: Not really an iText question but more a sql question.

Comment: No since a JOIN would return the name of the person for every row

Answer (score 2):

You can have one datatable, but have your query join the two tables.

```
SELECT p.PersonID, p.Name, a.AnimalID, a.PetName 
FROM person AS p
INNER JOIN animal AS a ON p.PersonID = a.PersonID
```

To do this cleanly, you'll want a new method like getPersonsAndAnimals() that returns the datatable with columns from both `person` and `animal`.

Comment: The problem with this is that i have the same person name for each animal. I wanted to have a summary for each person without repeating its name for every matched row

Comment: If the PersonID is the same as the previous value in the loop then `table.AddCell(new Phrase("", font5));` to not print the PersonID. Before the loop, declare `int PersonID = 0;`. At the end of each iteration of the loop set `PersonID = (int)r[0];`. At the start of each iteration check if `r[0] = PersonID`. If `true`, add a cell with the empty string, else add a cell with the PersonID.